# How to make android checkbox disable something in a layout?

Tags: java, android

Right now I have 4 checkboxes and I need to check if they're un-clicked. If they are then the next activity's layout needs to change. Right now I have the checkboxes on activity 1. Activity two gets a string variable from activity 1 and parses it into an int and checks if it was handed a zero or 1. Now on activity 2 there is a button to add things to that activity which pulls up a popup window.

```
public void newUserInput(View view){
        LayoutInflater inflater = (LayoutInflater)
                Launch.this.getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);

        PopupWindow pw = new PopupWindow(inflater.inflate(R.layout.popup_layout,null,false),300,400,true);

        pw.showAtLocation(findViewById(R.id.button1), Gravity.CENTER, 0, 0);
```

So... the popup window that pops up is what needs to be affected by what was clicked/unclicked in activity 1. My idea was to just check if it's zero and if it is then hide the text and text box for that entry. I'm just not too sure if I can do that? Also my popup window is absolute, which I figure if I hide one the others won't get pushed up to make it look cleaner, right?

Comment: Are you asking how do you check the state of the check boxes in activity 2?

Comment: @AndiJay No. Right now in activity 1 I have it checking to see if its checked and if it is I pass by extra to activity 2 where it parses it and saves that variable as an int. Then I'm checking if it equals 1 then I do nothing if it's zero then I need to hide a box in activity 3's layout (from activity 2, but activity 3 is just the popup box)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can definitely hide items in the layout based on your options. I'm not sure what your variables are called that hold the options but you could do something like the following.

```
public void newUserInput(View view) {
    LayoutInflater inflater = (LayoutInflater)
        Launch.this.getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);

    View inflatedView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.popup_layout,null,false);

    if (myOption == 0) {
        TextView tv = (TextView) inflatedView.findViewById(R.id.my_text_view);
        tv.setVisibility(TextView.INVISIBLE);
    }

    PopupWindow pw = new PopupWindow(inflatedView,300,400,true);

    pw.showAtLocation(findViewById(R.id.button1), Gravity.CENTER, 0, 0);
}
```

It's important to note that TextView.INVISIBLE will only make the TextView invisible... it will not remove it from the layout, so your styling should look the same as if it were visible. If you wanted to remove the TextView from the layout completely then you can use TextView.GONE.

Comment: where you have "TextView tv = (TextView) inflatedView.findViewById(R.id.my_text_view);" what exactly is the infladedView? It isnt showing up for me

Comment: If you look 2 lines above that line the layout is being inflated to be used as a view. All this is doing is instantiating the elements in that layout so that they are available to you as actual objects.

Comment: So... Would I be putting the setVisibility in the actual popup class?

Comment: Ideally you would set the visibility of the `TextView` or any other element in the `popup_layout` before you load the `PopupWindow`.

Comment: To go a little more in depth: in the newUserInput should I be passing the variables to the popup class and in the popup class on create I would disable or enable the boxes?

Comment: In my opinion thats just personal preference. Personally I would use the options in the activity in which they are defined to maintain separation of concerns. Basically, the popup doesn't need to decide how it is displayed since its parent can simply tell it how to display, using your options.

Comment: Right, but for some reason it isn't working. I'm going to go ahead and assume that the numbers being sent over are not being saved or not being sent. I wish there was some way to direct message you so don't have to clutter this whole place up or ask another question entirely.

Comment: Yeah, without seeing more of your I don't know how much more information I am able to give you about why it doesn't work.

Comment: if (addressChck == 2)
  {
      View inflatedView =     inflater.inflate(R.layout.popup_layout,null,false);
   TextView tv = (TextView) inflatedView.findViewById(R.id.address2);
   tv.setVisibility(TextView.GONE);
  }
     else
     {
      
     }
     
     
     PopupWindow pw = new PopupWindow(inflater.inflate(R.layout.popup_layout,null,false),300,400,true);
     pw.showAtLocation(findViewById(R.id.button1), Gravity.CENTER, 0, 0);

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/16057/discussion-between-japino-and-nogg)

Answer (score 0):

A couple ideas:

Activity 2 can conditionally load different layouts.
OR,
you can use View.setVisibility(View.GONE); to hide a view (or ViewGroup) from your layout.

So if you have for example a bunch of RelativeLayouts (layout1, layout2, layout3) that are stacked, if you do layout2.setVisibility(View.GONE), the layout will draw as if it doesn't exist.

Comment: As of now I just have one layout for the popup. How do I use the View.setVisibility(View.GONE) in the activity 2? Basically before the popup has started. so activity 1 goes to activity 2 and from activity 2 you can launch the popup.

Comment: if you're asking how to pass information to Activity 2 (e.g. the state of the checkboxes), you can use Intent extras.  My answer is geared towards how to remove stuff from your layout programmatically

Comment: No, I understand how to use the intent extras. Thats what I did. I want to know how to act on that in activity 2 so when activity 3 starts (the popup window) will be altered.